# Can I define a parent group and children groups?

Tags: permissions, users, groups

In Linux is it possible to create a master group and some children groups?

What is the problem?

I need to give read permission to the users belong to *group1* and *group2*.

I cannot add all users of the two groups to a third group *master* because I have too many users and they are quite dynamic in number.

Can I add *group1* and *group2* as children of *master*?

Comment: No, that's not how groups work .. Access Control Lists (ACLs) are the way to go. Read `man 5 acl;man setfacl`